# Laravel 5.6 OCI works fine with "php artisan serve" but Nginx can not find oci_connect()

Tags: nginx, laravel-5, php-7, oracle-call-interface, instantclient

I am trying to set up Laravel 5.6 + PHP 7.2 (with Instantclient 12.2 and oracle OCI) + Nginx on Ubuntu 18.2. Also, I have installed "yajra/laravel-oci8": "^5.6" for Laravel. To make sure I have instantclient installed correctly, I also tried sqlplus to make sure I can establish connection with the oracle server.

So, I should have everything configured properly and the oracle connector works fine when I serve the page with "**php artisan serve --host=192.168.56.12 --port=8000**" command.

The test code is as follows:

```
public function testorcl(){
    if (function_exists('oci_connect') == false){
        return "oci driver not available";
    }
}
```

At same time, I have Nginx enabled on the **default port 80**. 
Both web server are serving the same Laravel code base.

Strangely, **Nginx** can not find the oci_connect()!!

Then, I check phpinfo() page on both servers.

[image]

I found out that the oci8 module is **not mounted on Nginx server**. But, the "php artisan serve" shows oci8 is mounted. The oci8 module mounted should display something like the following image.
[image]

Not only the oci8 module part is different, the environment variables lists are also different. 
Nginx gives only 4 environment variables shown below while php artisan provides a long list of variables (which is too long to be displayed here in a single page).
[image]

So, I think it's the Nginx that causes the problem. Here is my Nginx configuration.

```
server {
         listen 80;
         listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

         # Log files for Debugging
         access_log /var/log/nginx/laravel-access.log;
         error_log /var/log/nginx/laravel-error.log;

         # Webroot Directory for Laravel project
         root /home/ub18/test/public;
         index index.php index.html index.htm;

         # Your Domain Name
         #server_name example.com;

         location / {
                 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
         }

         # PHP-FPM Configuration Nginx
         location ~ \.php$ {
                 try_files $uri =404;
                 fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                 fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                 fastcgi_index index.php;
                 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
                 include fastcgi_params;
         }

    # deny access to . files, for security
    #
    location ~ /\. {
        log_not_found off; 
        deny all;
    }
 }
```

The questions are:
1. How to make my OCI work? What did I miss out? 
2. How I can make sure Nginx can load the correct environment variables just like "**php artisan serve**"?

Any suggestions are welcomed, thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?  I wasn't able to get `oci_connect()` to work.  My only out at the moment is to uninstall Nginx and try Apache instead!!

Comment: I just noticed that your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should be pointing to `$ORACLE_HOME/bin`, and not to the same location as Oracle Home. This *could* be a (but might not be a full) solution to your problem.